# How to Measure differential conductance dI/dV experimentally?

Tags: design, electrical

Numerical derivation of IV curve is always a possibility to deduce dI/dV graph.
How to measure it directly in voltage bias mode?
What concept is required for it?
What instrument are required to measure dI/dV?

Comment: dI/dV of what? A transistor?

Answer (score 2):

There's many ways to measure it.

I assume you're interested in the differential resistance of a two-terminal device, or of a port on an n-port device.

You could use a semiconductor parameter analyzer to sweep voltage or current and measure the response, then take a numerical derivative.

You could use a function generator (possibly with a circuit to bias the device to the interesting operating point) to apply a sinusoidal voltage, and measure the current response.

You could use a vector network analyzer to measure the RF reflection coefficient at a particular bias point and determine the resistance from that.

Comment: Yeah Thanks for the asnswer.
I am interested in second one.
I am really novice in circuit design and I'm sorry.
I have a Lock-in as sinusoidal Voltage source, DC Current source and Multimeter.
Can you please help me how to make it functional.
How can I design the circuit?
What concept it uses?
Any other instument is required for it?

Comment: @Greg, if you have more questions you should post them as new questions.